# How to call method in all class children in C#?

Tags: c#, class, parent-child, children

I have a parent class and a number of child classes. What I want to do is to call a method in the parent class and it would execute in all child classes aswell, without referencing them ceparately.

Something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
public static void SomeMethod(){}
}
//certain amount of child classes
public void MainMethod(){
Parent.SomeMethod(); //Gets executed in all children
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I dont see a parent/child relation here. I would start with that. If you have done that; probably you want to leave out the "static".

Comment: As far as I understand, you may check the observable pattern. It specifies communication between objects: observable and observers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from your question, you need the *child* classes to have access to the same function as the parent. Among other options, I think you can use an abstract class to handle that. Just call the method once in the parent class, other child classes will do that as well. 
Also, it is flexible, bearing in mind the possibility of overriding the method in the child classes, if the need arises. See `ChildB` implementation.

**A sample.**

```
public abstract class FamilyBase
{
    public virtual void DoChores(FamilyBase member)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Chores by: "+member);
    }
}
public class Parent: FamilyBase
{
    public Parent()
    {

    }
    private List<FamilyBase> family=new List<FamilyBase>();

    public void AddMember(FamilyBase member)
    {
        family.Add(member);
    }
    //send out chores
    public void SendOutMessages()
    {
      if(family.Count>0)
      {
          foreach(var member in family)
          {
              member.DoChores(member);
          }
      }
    }
}
public class ChildA:FamilyBase
{
    public ChildA()
    {

    }
}
public class ChildB:FamilyBase
{
    public ChildB()
    {

    }
    public override void DoChores(FamilyBase member)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm doing my homework first.");
        base.DoChores(member);
    }
}
```

Send out messages from the parent.

```
Parent par=new Parent();
parent.AddMember(new ChildA());
parent.AddMember(new ChildB());
parent.SendOutMessages();
```

Output:

```
Doing Chores by : Parent
Doing Chores by : ChildA
I'm doing my homework first.
Doing Chores by : ChildB
```